# concatenate string in php foreach

Tags: php

I should be able to figure this out, but I keep going in circles.  I have a form with checkboxes.  When the checkboxes are selected they tagged to be deleted.

I process those selected checkboxes with a foreach:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST['checkboxselect']) as $k) {
    $str .= $k.',';
}
```

This is my lame attempt to put the list of videos together. The sql delete I'm using is:

```
DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `video_name` IN ($str)
```

So I'm missing lots of things here.  The `$str` needs to have:

1. Only one checkbox is returned so return string with quotes (i.e. "myvideo.mp4")
2. Multiple checkboxes are selected so build a string with quotes and commas (i.e. "myvideo.mp4","myvideo2.mp4","myvideo3.mp4")

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PHP's [implode](http://us.php.net/implode):

```
// Init links
$mysqliLink = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

$mysqlLink = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

//-----
// Prep values for query
//-----

// Only pick one of the following depending upon the mysql library you are using

// If using mysql, passing the 2nd argument is not necessary, but for 
// clarity, adding it
$deleteNames = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_keys($_POST['checkboxselect']), array_fill(0, count($_POST['checkboxselect']), $mysqlLink));

// If using mysqli
// This will ensure that $mysqliLink will be passed in as first arg for 
// every iteration satisfying the function signature
$deleteNames = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', array_fill(0, count($_POST['checkboxselect']), $mysqliLink), array_keys($_POST['checkboxselect']));
//-----


// Because you are passing strings, we need to ensure each is wrapped in quotes
$deleteNames = "'" . implode("','", $deleteNames) . "'";

// Construct query using implode
$sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `video_name` IN (%s)', $deleteNames);
```

**-- Update --**

Using Joomla APIs:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

// Localize and sanitize each individual value
foreach (array_keys($_POST['checkboxselect']) as $element) {
    $deleteNames[] = $db->quote($element);
}

// Because you are passing strings, we need to ensure each is wrapped in quotes
// No longer true because $db->quote taking care of quoting out each name for us
$deleteNames = implode(',', $deleteNames);

// Construct query using implode
$sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `video_name` IN (%s)', $deleteNames);
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for security in mind. But this didn't work.  But interested to know why...

Comment: I'm interested as well. What specifically didn't work? If you `var_dump($sql)` it should give you what you wanted.

Comment: Typo regarding `$myArray` and `$deleteIds`.

Comment: @MikePurcell Purcell The strings are all empty (I noticed the problem with the variables before and fixed that). If I var_dump each line it seems the implode line is where it goes wrong.  Although the first var_dump on array_map will return: `["video_0.mp4"]=> bool(false)`.  Not sure why it says `bool(false)`.

Comment: Ahhh I think I know why, I forgot to add `array_keys` around the `$_POST['checkboxselect']`. Updated post.

Comment: Better results from the first line but the implode line still returns empty strings.

Comment: Might be that you are using mysqli, vs mysql. I updated post to handle either scenario.

Comment: I really should have mentioned that I'm using Joomla so there are some things that are different. DB access is with `$db = &JFactory::getDBO();`. Extra security precautions are taken with `$checkbox_select = JRequest::getVar('checkboxselect', '', 'POST');` and for sql injections I should be using `$db->quote($selectedcheckboxes)` where `$selectedcheckboxes` is the result of the implode line.  Been trying to use all this with what you have provided is proving challenging. I'm not sure how to put everything together on your last edit. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Updated with Joomla syntax as provided by your comment. See if that works.

Comment: Thx for sticking with this! Too many quotes because of `db->quote` but I just fixed this line: `$deleteNames = implode(',', $deleteNames);` and it works great!

Comment: Outstanding. No problem, I updated post to reflect your findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode()` like this:

```
$str = '"' . implode('","', array_keys($_POST['checkboxselect'])) . '"';
```

`implode()` will take an array and join each value in the array with the "glue" string. In this case the "glue" is `","` and the array is composed of the keys in `$_POST['checkboxselect']`. Finally, the resulting string is wrapped in `"`.

This will result in your desired example string `"myvideo.mp4","myvideo2.mp4","myvideo3.mp4"`.